# An HTTP proxy in go

Tags: http, proxy, go

I'm writing a simple proxy in go that relays an HTTP request to one or more backend servers. Right now I'm still using only one backend server, but performance is not good and I'm sure I am doing something wrong. Probably related to how I send the HTTP request to another server: if I comment the call to `send()` then the server goes blazing fast, yielding more than 14 krps. While with the call to `send()` performance drops to less than 1 krps and drops even lower with time. This on a MacBook Pro.

The code is based on trivial code samples; I have created the `client` and reused it following the recommendation in the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-overview). Tests are done with Apache `ab`:

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 10 -k "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test"
```

The backend server running on port 55455 does not change between experiments; Apache or nginx can be used. My custom web server yields more than 7 krps when measured directly, without proxy:

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 10 -k "http://127.0.0.1:55455/test"
```

I would expect the proxied version to behave just as well as the non-proxied version, and sustain the performance over time.

The complete sample code follows.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        )

func main() {

        tr := &http.Transport{
                DisableCompression: true,
                DisableKeepAlives: false,
        }
        client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

        http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

                send(r, client)
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "OK")
        })
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func send(r *http.Request, client *http.Client) int {

        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:55455" + r.URL.Path, nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                return 0
        }       
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                return 0
        }       
        if resp == nil {
                return 0
        }       
        return 1
}
```

Eventually the code should send the request to multiple servers and process their answers, returning an int with the result. But I'm stuck at this step of just making the call.

What am I doing horribly wrong?

Comment: First tip: don't use Apache bench. It's a poor tool that is often bottlenecked well before your application is. wrk (https://github.com/wg/wrk) is probably the 'best' in this space, noting that HTTP benchmarking is far from perfect. Heck, half the time you're just benchmarking loopback adapter throughput rather than anything else. I should also note that `return 0` is not idiomatic Go: you should `return err` or `return errors.New("something")` (define common errors as package globals) so the caller knows *why* something returned early.

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look at [goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy/)

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich, with your experience with goproxy you can surely spot what's wrong in my puny code. I don't know enough Go to read its source code yet. Also, do you think that extending it for my evil purposes would be possible, or worth it?

Comment: @alexfernandez I definitely think and hope that extending it would be wirth it. What was wrong with the given answer?

Comment: Nothing, the given answer was spot-on. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich, can goproxy run on multiple cores? My current code only works on one core.

Comment: @alexfernandez: your code should work on multiple cores -- just run with `GOMAXPROCS` > 1 (the built-in http server is concurrent by default).

Comment: @alexfernandez and ditto for goproxy. It uses standard `net/http` server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comment suggests, you should be returning (and dealing with) type error instead of ints, and to reiterate, don't use AB.  The biggest thing that stands out to me is

1. You should set the `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` in your `Transport`.  This represents how many connections will persist (keep-alive) even if they have nothing to do at the moment.
2. You **have to read and close** the body of the response in order for it to be returned to the pool.

---

```
...
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
...
```

Comment: The results are encouraging: now it runs at 6k, almost as fast as without the query. I don't see the point of wrk, though: in my tests it consumes more cpu than ab, and gives worse results.

Comment: @alexfernandez: you mean `ab` happens to skew the results in your favor? If `wrk` doesn't suit you, maybe `weighttp` will work better. HTTP load testing is hard, none of the tools are really great, so I recommend using a variety of methods (and `ab` is usually last on my list`)

Comment: Thanks, it may come in handy. In this particular situation though, `ab` is giving consistent results.